# When needing to serialize EndpointDiscoveryMetadata, which wrapper to use: CD1, 11, or April2005?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

Since EndpointDiscoveryMetadata itself is not serializable, there are 3 wrapper class provided to help to accomplish serializing it:

1. EndpointDiscoveryMetadataApril2005
2. EndpointDiscoveryMetadata11
3. EndpointDiscoveryMetadataCD1

Which one should be used or does it matter? When would you use one over the other? Which is newer (or the latest version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like EndpointDiscoveryMetadata11 is the most [recent version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/discovery/archive/2009/07/01/ws-discovery-is-now-an-oasis-approved-standard.aspx).